# Android admob banner

Tags: java, android, admob

How can I set the width, the height, the pixels left and the pixels top of a admob android ad banner? I tied to use this code:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.optionslayout);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "...ID...");

    layout.addView(adView);

    adView.setTop(layout.getHeight()/2 - adView.getHeight()/2);
    adView.setLeft((int) (100*density));

    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

But when I try to run this Activity it stops unexpectedly. Is there any solution for this problem? I also tried setX() and setY()!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define adView in Layout xml, and set these params there only.

and in your activity do this
  `adView = (AdView) findViewByID(R.id.adX);`

instead of

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "...ID...");
```

Comment: And one more information: How can I rotate the banner? I tried this:
RotateAnimation rotate = (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
adView.startAnimation(rotate);